# How to send a HTML code as gmail body using wso2 gmail connector and wso2 esb?

Tags: gmail, wso2, gmail-api, connector, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb and wso2 gmail connector to send an email as follows. But I need to send an html code (it displays a simple table) as the messageBody instead of a simple text.I searched on that, but only found examples with messageBuilder not with Gmail connector. I tried using script and xslt mediators. But i'm struggling with the part to send the created html code with the connector. So can anyone has an idea on how to do this?

```
<gmail.init>
        <userId>{$ctx:userId}</userId>
        <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
        <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
</gmail.init>
<gmail.sendMail>
        <to>{$ctx:to}</to>
        <subject>{$ctx:subject}</subject>
        <from>{$ctx:from}</from>
        <messageBody>{$ctx:msgHeader}</messageBody>
</gmail.sendMail>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now able to achieve this with the new connector can found in https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/74539b71-3b72-49c1-a21a-f08ad7d7d4ad ,

and the documentation can found in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Messages+in+Gmail#WorkingwithMessagesinGmail-sendMail